# C++ ending parenthesis with - instead of. )

Tags: c++

While trying to find help for a problem I have, I've seen someone use a code like this to search a string. I cannot seem to find an answer as to what the minus between the 2 `line.find()` operators means. Is it point a to point b, or is it subtracting?

```
minutes = line.substr(line.find(" ") + 1, line.find("h") - line.find(" ") - 1);
```

Comment: Hmmm, looks like they are using [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).  Here's the description of the **Return Value**:  *Position of the first character of the found substring or npos if no such substring is found.*  So, adding 1 to the return value is the position of the next character after the found character.  This is Undefined Behavior if any of the `find` functions fail.

Comment: Write down each character on a piece of paper.  Above each character, write its position.  This should give you a good visual of what the statement is performing.

Comment: There is no "C++ ending parenthesis with - instead of. )" here. Please fix your title to express your actual question.

Comment: A search engine is not a replacement for a C++ textbook. The proper way to learn C++ is to get a good C++ textbook, open chapter 1, and start reading. Looking at random bits of C++ code, and trying to figure out its syntax by running search engine queries, will never be productive and will always end in tears.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably `line` is a `std::string`. [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns the index where the substring provided can be found.

```
line.find(" ") + 1
```

This returns the index immediately after the one where `" "` can be found in `line`.

```
line.find("h") - line.find(" ") - 1
```

This is doing math on the indices where `"h"` and `" "` can be found.

If `line` is `"  hello world! "`, then `line.find(" ")` returns `0` and `line.find("h")` returns `2`. Thus we get to `line.substr(0 + 1, 2 - 0 - 1)` or `line.substr(1, 1)`. [`std::string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) takes a start position and a number of characters to include.

|  |  | h | e | l | l | o |  | w | o | r | l | d |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |

Getting a substring of length 1 starting at index 1 yields `" "`.